# Advanced author permalinks

Tags: permalinks, customization, archives, author

I'm trying to build permalink structure for author archives that would allow me to display different custom post types posts in 'subpages/subarchives' of author archive.

So the idea is to change this:
/%author_base%/%user_name%/

Into this:
/%author_base%/%user_name%/%CPT_slug%/

I'd be greatful for suggestions.